# removing multiple spaces in c++ from string

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code to open a file and read the data from it, then take the relavent part and print it to screen.

```
char* search = "model name";
int Offset;
string Cpu;
ifstream CpuInfo;
CpuInfo.open ("/proc/cpuinfo");

if(CpuInfo.is_open())
{
  while(!CpuInfo.eof())
  {
    getline(CpuInfo,Cpu);
    if ((Offset = Cpu.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
    {
       //cout << "found '" << search << " " << line << endl;
       break;
    }
  }
  CpuInfo.close();
}
Cpu.replace (0,13,"");

cout << Cpu
```

This usually outputs the type of CPU your using, but one problem is that some people have various spaces inbetween the words that it prints out.

My question is how to remove all the spaces from inbetween the words. They can of random ammount and aren't always present.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you remove *all* of them I'm fairly sure you search for a pair of words separated by *a space* will come up dry.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question states:  **"how to remove all the spaces from inbetween the words"**:

You can use `std::remove_if` from the standard `<algorithm>` library in addition to `std::isspace`:

```
std::string mystring = "Text with some   spaces";
std::remove_if(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), std::isspace);
```

This now becomes:

```
Textwithsomespaces
```

REFERENCES:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove